# Application crash caused by lazy on API 19

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, singleton, lazy-initialization

I use singleton object in my app and provide context to it from `Application` class.
And i use `by lazy {}` delegate for set `sharedPreferences` field. It's working on API 21 and higher, but on API 19 i has a `NoClassDefFoundError`:

```
08-04 16:20:24.075 5576-5576/ru.maxim.barybians E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ru.maxim.barybians, PID: 5576
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ru.maxim.barybians.repository.local.PreferencesManager$sharedPreferences$2
        at ru.maxim.barybians.repository.local.PreferencesManager.<clinit>(PreferencesManager.kt:15)
        at ru.maxim.barybians.App.onCreate(App.kt:14)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4344)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Singleton object**

```
object PreferencesManager {
    
    lateinit var context: Context
    private val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences by lazy { PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context) }
```

**App class**

```kotlin
class App : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        PreferencesManager.context = applicationContext
    }
```

```
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 29
kotlin_version = '1.3.72'
Gradle Version = 6.1.1
Gradle Plugin Version = 4.0.1
```

Changing Gradle version or invalidating cache not working for me.
I will be grateful for any help

Answer (score 1):

I finnaly foun the solution. Application crashes because class `App` inherited from `Application`. After i change it to `MultiDexApplication`, application began to work normally.

`class App : MultiDexApplication()`